# Another typedef error with C++

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H
#include <memory>
class C
{
public:
    C(){};
    ~C() {};
};
typedef auto_ptr<C> CPtr;


#endif
```

The above codes seem fine for me, but when I compile them with VC10, I got the following errors:
"error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'". Any ideas about it will be appreciated.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the C++ 11 standard states that: _`auto_ptr` has been deprecated and that `unique_ptr` provides a better solution_.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We have a mechanism for saying "Problem solved, this was the solution: ...", which is to click the green check-mark next to the correct (and in this case only) answer. There might be a time delay before you are allowed to do this, but we prefer this to editing your question to add the same information. :)

Comment: Now I am using STLPort, and it seems that this library does not support unique_ptr yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#include <memory>` gives you `auto_ptr` in the `std`-namespace, so you could make this compile by replacing your `typedef` with:

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<C> CPtr;
```

Alternatively, you could introduce `auto_ptr` into the current namespace with a `using` statement, though you should really not do this in a header. To do this you would need to add a statement like `using std::auto_ptr;` or `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @feelfree, you should accept this answer rather than updating the question with the solution.

Comment: Ok, I will do that as you suggested.